# Confirm AC generator output frequency calculation

Tags: generator, three-phase

I am working on a project to build a small generator based on a 12 magnet, 12 pole, (6 pole pair) rotor with shaft speed of 2800 RPM. (Output voltage, 240 V AC, 4 kW.)

Estimated load will be 3.5 kW,  constant on heating elements. 
The value of output frequency concerns me though. Can some one confirm the formula (RPM / 60 x 6) provided by the seller. The value calculated seems high at 280 Hz or have I just failed to understand.

Will the frequency be suitable for the heating elements designed to be used at 50 Hz?

Comment: Unless something is very strange, why do you care about frequency in  a heating element? If it's 20 Hz or 50 Hz, what does it matter?

Comment: Please clarify what you have (motor), what you have to build (generator), and the load (resistive). Resistive loads have little effect based on such low drive frequencies (50 or 60HZ).

Comment: For resistive heating, the only thing you should be concerned with is the RMS output voltage. If you're not working with a rectified DC bus, then frequency below a couple of kHz likely won't matter to a resistor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The synchronous speed for an electric induction motor is determined by the power supply frequency and the number of poles in the motor winding and can be expressed as:

$$ n = f \frac {2}{p} 60 $$

where

- n = shaft rotation speed (rev/min, rpm)
- f = frequency (Hz, cycles/sec, 1/s)
- p = number of poles
- 60 = number of seconds in a minute

Rearranging for f we get

$$ f = \frac {n \cdot p}{2 \cdot 60} $$

> Based on a ... 12 pole, 2800 RPM ...

$$ f = \frac {2800 \cdot 12}{2 \cdot 60} = 280~Hz$$

Your calculations are correct. Your frequency is rather unusual.

> Will the frequency be suitable for the heating elements designed to be used at 50 Hz?

If the heating elements are just resistive they will behave normally at these low frequencies. If they exhibit significant inductance their impedance to AC will rise with frequency. It's unlikely to be a problem for water heaters as they use straightish elements rather than coils of wire.

Be careful not to run transformers or relay coils from this 280 Hz supply unless you have confirmed that they are suitable.